How to remove the null value of a selectpicker or display the menu entirely?
My selectpicker can contain a number of values depending on certain parameters. You can also search the selectpicker using the data-live-search="true" attribute. I have a problem: when there is only one option to display, I have to scroll down the menu. It is easy to interpret that the search did not give a result when searching.
I tried to modify the CSS using overflow-y: visible !important. However, this did not work. I also tried to remove the empty option by using a selectpicker('refresh') to see the list of values. However, this will alter the rendering, even if you first remove the selectpicker.
Perhaps you have already encountered this problem and managed to solve it.
I use this:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
Bootstrap v5.1.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)


Here some pictures of my application. As you can see, there is a default scroll bar that I’m forced to use to access my only option.
Here, my only JavaScript code regarding the selectpicker :
$('.selectpicker').on('hidden.bs.select', function() {
     $(this).closest('.bootstrap-select').find('.dropdown-menu').attr('hidden', true);
});

$('.selectpicker').on('shown.bs.select', function() {
     $(this).closest('.bootstrap-select').find('.dropdown-menu').attr('hidden', false);
});

And here, how i render my selectpicker :
<select name="materiel[]" class="selectpicker form-control" id="materiel_autre" data-live-search="true" multiple>
     @foreach($type_materiels as $type)
          @if($type->id == 2)
               @foreach($type->sous_type as $ss_type)
                    @foreach($ss_type->materiel as $materiel)
                         @if($materiel->site_id == $site->id)
                              <option value="{{$materiel->id}}">{{$materiel->libelle}}</option>
                         @endif
                    @endforeach
               @endforeach
          @endif
     @endforeach
</select>


It looks like it's the default behavior when it's a multiple select. You could always check to see if you're outputting the first option, and if so, set it to "selected"

I can’t put select on my option because this field is optional.

Oh, I misunderstood the problem. Double-check the source of the browser to see if there are any empty options listed, or why there's an empty line above the listed options.

Yes, there are an empty line, i think its generated by selectpicker, here the line :
<li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-2-0" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span class="text">Balai de cantonnier</span></a></li>
